# No GDAL/OGR package for Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: gdal, ogr, ubuntu

Using Ubuntu 15.04, I'm trying to install GDAL/OGR.

I did:

```
[] sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
[] sudo apt-get update
```

However, I found this error message

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Actually, there is no package for Vivid (Ubuntu 15.04)
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu/dists/

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Fixed by modifying the file 'ubuntugis-ubuntu-ppa-vivid.list'

Comment: How did you modify the list? My list is empty.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the ubuntugis repositories don't get updated to new Ubuntu versions.

You may find current GDAL ubuntu packages here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdal

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/+package/gdal-bin